# Create a dataframe from a list of a list of matrices/vectors/lists in R

Tags: r

I have a list with 2 elements, each element being itself a mixed list of matrices, vectors or list.

The first level of list (containing 2 elements) should not matter but the next level contains the names of samples that I would like to be the column names of an output dataframe. The rows should number 22 and the values are a character vector as below. I've only shown the first three columns and four rows of the desired output.

How can I do this in R?

**DESIRED OUTPUT**:

```
SD.A5.A0R6.ZZ   SD.AX.A2HC.ZZ   SD.DI.A2QY.ZZ ....
c(0,0)          c(0)            c(0,0)
c(0,0)          c(0)            c(0,0)
c(0,0)          c(0)            c(0,0)
c(0,"down")     c(0)            c(0,"down")
...             ...             ...
```

**INPUT**:

```
list(structure(list(SD.A5.A0R6.ZZ = structure(c("0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "down", "0", "down", "0", "down", "down", 
"0", "0", "0", "down", "0", "0", "down", "0", "down", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "down", "0", "down", "0", "0", "down", "0", "0", 
"up", "0", "0", "0", "down", "up", "down", "0", "0"), .Dim = c(2L, 
22L)), SD.AX.A2HC.ZZ = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"up", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "up", 
"0", "0", "0", "0"), SD.DI.A2QY.ZZ = list(c("0", "0"), c("0", 
"0"), c("0", "0"), c("0", "down"), c("0", "down"), c("0", "up"
), c("0", "up"), c("up", "down"), c("0", "down"), c("0", 
"0"), c("0", "down"), c("0", "down"), c("up", "down"), c("0", 
"up", "up"), c("0", "down"), c("down", "0"), c("down", "up"
), c("0", "up"), c("down", "0"), c("0", "up"), c("0", "down", 
"up"), c("0", "down"))), .Names = c("SD.A5.A0R6.ZZ", "SD.AX.A2HC.ZZ", 
"SD.DI.A2QY.ZZ")), structure(list(SD.N5.A4RV.ZZ = list(
    c("0", "0"), c("0", "down"), c("0", "down"), c("0", "0"), 
    c("0", "down"), c("0", "up"), c("0", "down"), c("0", "0"
    ), c("down", "0"), c("0", "down"), c("0", "down"), c("0", 
    "down"), c("down", "up"), c("0", "down"), c("0", "down", 
    "up"), c("0", "down", "down"), c("down", "0"), c("0", "0"
    ), c("0", "0"), c("0", "0"), c("0", "down"), c("0", "0")), 
    SD.N6.A4VF.ZZ = list("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
        "up", "down", "down", "0", "0", c("down", "up"), 
        "0", "0", "down", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "down"), SD.NA.A4QW.ZZ = list(
        c("0", "down", "down", "0"), c("0", "0", "down", "down"
        ), c("0", "down", "down", "down", "up"), c("0", "down", 
        "down", "0"), c("down", "0", "up"), c("0", "down", 
        "down", "0"), c("0", "down", "down"), c("down", "up", 
        "0"), c("down", "0", "0"), c("0", "down", "down"), c("0", 
        "0", "down", "down"), c("down", "0", "0"), c("0", "down", 
        "0"), c("0", "down", "down", "up", "up"), c("0", 
        "down", "down", "down"), c("0", "down", "down", "0"), 
        c("0", "down", "down"), c("0", "down", "down", "0"), 
        c("0", "up", "0"), c("0", "down", "down", "down", "up"
        ), c("0", "down", "down", "down"), c("0", "down", "down"
        ))), .Names = c("SD.N5.A4RV.ZZ", "SD.N6.A4VF.ZZ", 
"SD.NA.A4QW.ZZ")))
```

Comment: ... what created this monster? All joking aside, the lack of consistency in type as you go down will make this very difficult to parse. It might make more sense to re-evaluate how you are creating/reading the data

Comment: I was given the data unfortunately. Is there anyway to process it before putting it into the dataframe?

Comment: A general solution here would likely be very complex, as you would need to let it handle all of the exceptions. If this is the entire data set, it is probably not unfeasible to extract the matrices manually one by one. If it is not the entire set, you would need to upload more of your data because we could not be assured a general solution exists without looking at all the different possible cases within.

Comment: Exhaustively, the 3rd level type will be numeric vector, list of characters and a character matrix. It's safe to assume this is all the data